# Simpletron simulator in C

Tags: c, virtual-machine

I implemented a Simpletron simulator in C for learning C.
Simpletron is a virtual machine invented by Deitel for his books. Simpletron runs programs written in the Simpletron Machine Language, an simple Machine Language.

An instruction (and data) in the Simpletron Machine Language is a signed four-digit integer, like `+1009`. The first two digits are the opcode, and the last two digits are the operand.

I wrote a manual for the Simpletron Simulator in troff, it contains the instructions of the Simpletron Machine Language and some example programs.

Here's the manual, read it using the command man(1):

```
simpletron(6)                   Games Manual                  simpletron(6)

NAME
       simpletron - simulates a simpletron computer

SYNOPSIS
       simpletron [-c] [-m memsize] file

DESCRIPTION
       simpletron  simulates  a  simpletron  machine running a program con‐
       tained in file and written in SML, the Simpletron Machine Language.

       The options are as follows:

       -c     Do a computer dump at the end of the simulation.  A core dump
              prints  the name and contents of each register as well as the
              complete contents of memory.

       -m memsize
              Set the size of the memory of the Simpletron simulator.   The
              memory  must  be  big enough to hold the instructions and the
              data.

       The input have the same format as instruction (see the  section  THE
       SIMPLETRON  MACHINE LANGUAGE for information on the instruction syn‐
       tax).

THE SIMPLETRON SIMULATOR
       For information on how to implementate a Simpletron simulator,  read
       the README file provided with the code.

   The memory
       All  information  in the Simpletron is handled in terms of words.  A
       word is a signed four-digit decimal number  such  as  +3364,  -1293,
       +0007, -0001, and so on.

       The Simpletron is equipped with a 100-word memory by default (but it
       can be expanded with the -m option).  Each word  in  the  memory  is
       referenced by their two-digit location numbers 00, 01, ..., 99.  The
       location 00 is the location of the first word, 01 is the location of
       the second word, and so on.

       Before  running  an  SML program, the Simpletron Simulator loads the
       programinto memory.  The first instruction of every program  is  al‐
       ways  placed in location 00.  Each location in the Simpletron's mem‐
       ory may contain either an instruction, a data value used by  a  pro‐
       gram, or an unused (and hence undefined) area of memory.

   The registers
       The  Simpletron has a single “general purpose” register known as the
       accumulator.  Information must be put on the accumulator before  the
       Simpletron  uses  that information in calculations or examines it in
       various ways.

       The Simpletron also has “special purpose” registers used  to  manage
       the  instruction execution cycle.  These registers cannot be changed
       directly.

       counter
              The instruction counter keep track of the  locationin  memory
              that contains the instruction being performed.

       instruction register
              The instruction register is a word containing the instruction
              currently being performed.

       opcode The opcode indicates the operation currently being performed.
              It  is  the  leftmost two digits of the instruction currently
              being performed.

       operand
              The operand indicates the memory location  or  the  immediate
              value  on  which the current instruction operates.  It is the
              rightmost two digits of the instruction currently being  per‐
              formed.

   The instruction execution cycle
       After  the  SML  program  has  been loaded into the memory, the Sim‐
       pletron simulator executes it.  It begins with  the  instruction  in
       location  00  and  continues  sequentially,  unless directed to some
       other part of the program by a transfer of control.

       The instruction execution cycle do as the following.

              The instruction counter tell the location  of  the  next  in‐
              struction to be performed.

              The contents of that location is fetched from memory into the
              instruction register.

              The operation code and the operand are extracted from the in‐
              struction register.

              The simpletron determines the operation to be executed.

              At  this point, the simulation of a instruction is completed.
              All that remains is to prepare the Simpletron to execute  the
              next  instruction.   So  the Simpletron ajust the instruction
              counter accordingly.

THE SIMPLETRON MACHINE LANGUAGE
       Each instruction written in the Simpletron  Machine  Language  (SML)
       occupies  one  word  of the Simpletron's memory, so instructions are
       signed four-digit decimal numbers.  We assume that the  sign  of  an
       SML  instruction  is always plus, but the sign of a data word may be
       either plus or minus.  An instruction is a plus-signed 4-digit  word
       composed of two parts: the 2-digit operation code (aka “opcode”) and
       the 2-digit operand.

       The first two digits of each SML instruction are the operation code,
       which  specifies the operation to be performed.  SML operation codes
       are summarized in the following sections between parentheses.

       The last two digits of an SML instruction are the operand, which  is
       either  the  address  of  the memory location containing the word to
       which the operation indirectly applies, or a value to which the  op‐
       eration directly applies.

       In a SML file, each line is a instruction, a instruction begins with
       a plus or minus sign followed by four decimal digits.  The remaining
       of the line is ignored.

   Input/output operations
       READ (10)
              Read  a  word  from  the terminal into a specific location in
              memory.

       WRITE (11)
              Write a word from a specific location in memory to the termi‐
              nal.

   Memory loading/storing
       LOAD (20)
              Loada  word from a specific location in memory into the accu‐
              mulator.

       STORE (21)
              Store a word from the accumulator into a specific location in
              memory.

   Memory arithmetic operations
       Note that all the results are left in accumulator.

       ADD (30)
              Add  a word from a specific location in memory to the word in
              the accumulator.

       SUBTRACT (31)
              Subtract a word from a specific location in memory  from  the
              word in the accumulator.

       DIVIDE (32)
              Divide  a  word  from  a specific location in memory into the
              word in the accumulator.

       MULTIPLY (33)
              Multiply a word from a specific location  in  memory  by  the
              word in the accumulator.

   Immediate arithmetic operations
       Note that all the results are left in accumulator.

       ADD_I (40)
              Add a the value in operand to the word in the accumulator.

       SUBTRACT_I (41)
              Subtract  the value in operand from the word in the accumula‐
              tor.

       DIVIDE_I (42)
              Divide the value in operand into the word in the accumulator.

       MULTIPLY_I (43)
              Multiply the value in operand by the word in the accumulator.

   Transfer-of-control operations
       BRANCH (50)
              Branch to a specific location in memory.

       BRANCHNEG (51)
              Branch to a specific location in memory if the accumulator is
              negative.

       BRANCHZERO (52)
              Branch to a specific location in memory if the accumulator is
              zero.

       HALT (53)
              Halt (i'e', the program has completed its task).

EXAMPLES
       The following are example of programs in the Simpletron Machine Lan‐
       guage (SML).

   adder.sml
       The  following  SML  program reads two numbers from the keyboard and
       computes and prints their sum.

              +1007   READ A
              +1008   READ B
              +2007   LOAD A
              +3008   ADD B
              +2109   STORE C
              +1109   WRITE C
              +5300   HALT
              +0000   A
              +0000   B
              +0000   C

       (1) The instruction +1007 reads the first number from  the  keyboard
       and places it into location 07 (which has been initialized to zero).

       (2) Then +1008 reads the next number into location 08.

       (3)  The load instruction (+2007) puts the first number into the ac‐
       cumulator.

       (4) The add instruction (+3008) adds the second number to the number
       in  theaccumulator.   All SML aritmetic instructions leave their re‐
       sults in the accumulator.

       (5) The store instruction (+2109) placesthe result back into  memory
       location 09.

       (6)  From  the  location 09, the write instruction (+1109) takes the
       number and prints it (as a signed four-digit decimal number).

       (7) The halt instruction (+4300) terminates the execution.

   larger.sml
       The following SML program reads two numbers from the  keyboard,  and
       determines  and  prints  the  larger value.  Note the use of the in‐
       struction +5107 as a conditional transfer of control, much the  same
       as C's if statement.

              +1009   READ A
              +1010   READ B
              +2009   LOAD A
              +3110   SUBTRACT B
              +5107   BRANCHNEG 07
              +1109   WRITE A
              +5300   HALT
              +1110   WRITE B
              +5300   HALT

   sum.sml
       The  following program uses a sentinel-controlled loop to read posi‐
       tive integers and compute and printe their sum.

              +1008   READ A
              +2008   LOAD A
              +5206   BRANCHZERO 06
              +3009   SUM B
              +2109   STORE B
              +5000   BRANCH 00
              +1109   WRITE B
              +5300   HALT
              +0000   A
              +0000   B

   average7.sml
       The following program uses a counter-controlled loop to  read  seven
       numbers,  some  positive  and  some  negative, and compute and print
       their average.

              +2015   LOAD N
              +5210   BRANCHZERO 10
              +1016   READ A
              +2016   LOAD A
              +3017   ADD B
              +2117   STORE B
              +2015   LOAD N
              +4101   SUB_I 01
              +2115   STORE N
              +5000   BRANCH 00
              +2017   LOAD B
              +4207   DIV_I 07
              +2117   STORE B
              +1117   WRITE B
              +5300   HALT
              +0007   N
              +0000   A
              +0000   B

EXIT STATUS
       0      Success.

       >0     Error occurred.

HISTORY
       This version of simpletron, the Simpletron Simulator,  is  based  on
       the exercises 7.27~7.29 from the [Deitel & Deitel] book.

       The  immediate  operations  are unique to this implementation, since
       the exercise does not mention them.

SEE ALSO
       [Deitel & Deitel]
              C: How to Program (8th edition), Paul Deitel and Harvey  Dei‐
              tel

                                                              simpletron(6)
```

And here is the Simpletron Simulator:

```
#include <err.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define DEFMEMSIZE      100
#define MEM_MAX         9999
#define MEM_MIN         -9999
#define INSTRUCTIONSIZE 4
#define OPSIZE          2

enum operation {
    READ       = 10,
    WRITE      = 11,
    LOAD       = 20,
    STORE      = 21,
    ADD        = 30,
    SUBTRACT   = 31,
    DIVIDE     = 32,
    MULTIPLY   = 33,
    REMINDER   = 34,
    ADD_I      = 40,
    SUBTRACT_I = 41,
    DIVIDE_I   = 42,
    MULTIPLY_I = 43,
    REMINDER_I = 44,
    BRANCH     = 50,
    BRANCHNEG  = 51,
    BRANCHZERO = 52,
    HALT       = 53
};

/* Simpletron's memory is simulated with a one-dimensional array */
static int *memory;
static int memsize = DEFMEMSIZE;

/* Simpletron's registers are simulated with the following variables */
static int acc;     /* accumulator register (value being processed) */
static int ireg;    /* instruction register (current instruction) */

static int simpletron(void);
static void load(FILE *);
static void dump(void);
static int getinstruction(FILE *, int *);
static int getmemsize(const char *s);
static void usage(void);

/* load a program in the Simpletron Machine Language into memory and execute it*/
int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int c, exitval, coredump;
    FILE *fp;

    coredump = 0;
    while ((c = getopt(argc, argv, "cm:")) != -1) {
        switch (c) {
        case 'm':
            if ((memsize = getmemsize(optarg)) < 1)
                errx(EXIT_FAILURE, "%s: improper memory size", optarg);
            break;
        case 'c':
            coredump = 1;
            break;
        default:
            usage();
            break;
        }
    }
    argc -= optind;
    argv += optind;

    if (argc != 1)
        usage();
    if ((memory = calloc(memsize, sizeof *memory)) == NULL)
        err(EXIT_FAILURE, NULL);
    if ((fp = fopen(*argv, "r")) == NULL)
        err(EXIT_FAILURE, "%s", *argv);

    load(fp);                   /* load program into memory */
    exitval = simpletron();     /* execute instructions in memory */
    if (coredump)
        dump();                 /* do coredump, if needed */
    free(memory);

    return exitval;
}

/* run instructions from memory; return 1 if error occurs, return 0 otherwise */
static int
simpletron(void)
{
    static int count;
    static int opcode;
    static int operand;

    /* memory location of next instruction */
    /* simulation begins with the instruction in the location 00 and continues sequentially */
    count = 0;

    /* this loop implements the "instruction execution cycle" */
    while (count < memsize) {
        ireg = memory[count];
        opcode = ireg / 100;  /* opcode is the leftmost two digits of instruction register*/
        operand = ireg % 100; /* operand is the rightmost two digits of instruction register*/

        /* this switch statement determine the operation to be performed */
        /* each case set the counter for next instruction accordingly */
        switch (opcode) {
        case READ:
            if (getinstruction(stdin, &memory[operand]) == 0) {
                warnx("improper input");
                return 1;
            }
            count++;
            break;
        case WRITE:
            printf("%+05d\n", memory[operand]);
            count++;
            break;
        case LOAD:
            acc = memory[operand];
            count++;
            break;
        case STORE:
            memory[operand] = acc;
            count++;
            break;
        case ADD:
            if ((memory[operand] > 0 && acc > MEM_MAX - memory[operand]) ||
                (memory[operand] < 0 && acc < MEM_MIN - memory[operand])) {
                warnx("integer overflow");
                return 1;
            }
            else
                acc += memory[operand];
            count++;
            break;
        case SUBTRACT:
            if ((memory[operand] > 0 && acc < MEM_MIN + memory[operand]) ||
                (memory[operand] < 0 && acc > MEM_MAX + memory[operand])) {
                warnx("integer overflow");
                return 1;
            }
            else
                acc -= memory[operand];
            count++;
            break;
        case DIVIDE:
            if (memory[operand] == 0) {
                warnx("division by zero");
                return 1;
            } else if ((acc == MEM_MIN) && (memory[operand] == -1)) {
                warnx("signed integer overflow");
                return 1;
            } else {
                acc /= memory[operand];
            }
            count++;
            break;
        case MULTIPLY:
            acc *= memory[operand];
            if (acc < MEM_MIN || acc > MEM_MAX) {
                warnx("integer overflow");
                return 1;
            }
            count++;
            break;
        case REMINDER:
            if (memory[operand] == 0) {
                warnx("remainder by zero");
                return 1;
            } else if ((acc == MEM_MIN) && (memory[operand] == -1)) {
                warnx("signed integer overflow");
                return 1;
            } else {
                acc %= memory[operand];
            }
            count++;
            break;
        case ADD_I:
            if ((operand > 0 && acc > MEM_MAX - operand) ||
                (operand < 0 && acc < MEM_MIN - operand)) {
                warnx("integer overflow");
                return 1;
            } else {
                acc += operand;
            }
            count++;
            break;
        case SUBTRACT_I:
            if ((operand > 0 && acc < MEM_MIN + operand) ||
                (operand < 0 && acc > MEM_MAX + operand)) {
                warnx("integer overflow");
                return 1;
            } else {
                acc -= operand;
            }
            count++;
            break;
        case DIVIDE_I:
            if (operand == 0) {
                warnx("division by zero");
                return 1;
            } else if ((acc == MEM_MIN) && (operand == -1)) {
                warnx("signed integer overflow");
                return 1;
            } else {
                acc /= operand;
            }
            count++;
            break;
        case MULTIPLY_I:
            acc *= operand;
            if (acc < MEM_MIN || acc > MEM_MAX) {
                warnx("integer overflow");
                return 1;
            }
            count++;
            break;
        case REMINDER_I:
            if (operand == 0) {
                warnx("remainder by zero");
                return 1;
            } else if ((acc == MEM_MIN) && (operand == -1)){
                warnx("signed integer overflow");
                return 1;
            } else {
                acc %= operand;
            }
            count++;
            break;
        case BRANCH:
            count = operand;
            break;
        case BRANCHNEG:
            if (acc < 0)
                count = operand;
            else
                count++;
            break;
        case BRANCHZERO:
            if (acc == 0)
                count = operand;
            else
                count++;
            break;
        case HALT:
            return 0;
        default:
            warnx("%+05d: invalid instruction", ireg);
            return 1;
        }
    }

    warnx("execution reached end of memory without halting");
    return 1;
}

/* load memory from file */
static void
load(FILE *fp)
{
    size_t i;
    int instruction;

    i = 0;
    while(getinstruction(fp, &instruction) && i < memsize)
        memory[i++] = instruction;
}

/* write a core dump of memory and registers into stdout */
static void
dump(void)
{
    size_t i, j;

    fprintf(stderr, "\nREGISTERS:\n"
           "accumulator          %+05d\n"
           "instruction register %+05d\n",
           acc, ireg);
    fprintf(stderr, "\nMEMORY:\n"
           "        0      1      2      3      4      5      6      7      8      9\n");
    for (i = 0; i < memsize / 10; i++) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%2lu  ", i * 10);
        for (j = 0; j < memsize / 10; j++)
            fprintf(stderr, "%+05d%s", memory[(i*10)+j],
                   (j == memsize / 10 - 1) ? "\n" : "  ");
    }
}

/* get instruction from fp; return 0 if instruction is improper */
static int
getinstruction(FILE *fp, int *instruction)
{
    size_t i;
    int c, num, sign;

    num = 0;

    /* get initial blank */
    while (isblank(c = getc(fp)))
        ;

    /* get instruction/data sign */
    sign = (c == '-') ? -1 : 1;
    if (c != '+' && c != '-')
        return 0;
    else
        c = getc(fp);

    /* get instruction/data number */
    for (i = 0; i < INSTRUCTIONSIZE; i++) {
        if (!isdigit(c))
            return 0;
        num = num * 10 + c - '0';
        c = getc(fp);
    }

    /* get remaining of command line */
    while (c != '\n' && c != EOF)
        c = getc(fp);

    *instruction = sign * num;
    return 1;
}

/* get an integer from s to be used as the memory size */
static int
getmemsize(const char *s)
{
    long n;
    char *endp;

    n = strtol(s, &endp, 10);

    if (errno == ERANGE || n > INT_MAX || n < INT_MIN || endp == s || *endp != '\0')
        return -1;
    return (int) n;
}

static void
usage(void)
{
    (void) fprintf(stderr, "usage: simpletron [-c] [-m memsize] file\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

Here is a sample program in the Simpletron Machine Language, average7.sml, it receives 7 values from input and calculates the average between them.

```
+1008
+2008
+5206
+3009
+2109
+5000
+1109
+5300
+0000
+0000
```

The input of a Simpletron program must be a signed four-digit integer, like `+0007` or `-0001`.

Is there any way I can make the code more elegant and portable?

Comment: (I had a look at the troff "source" without  syntax colouring - did not find it much improved.)

Comment: It might be more helpful if you displayed that help text in your console using `man` and pasted the formatted output here. It seems like an unnecessary hoop to jump through for reviewers otherwise. Unless the code of the man page is explicitly included in what you want reviewed, of course.

Comment: In the review below the section `Assignment-in-condition` is addressing code readability and maintainability, and it section is correct, your code is not as readable as it could be and someone could definitely miss the assignment statements.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In addition to the review you already have, I have a few more suggestions.

### Fix the bug

As was already pointed out, the *assignment-in-condition* practice is problematic.  In this particular case, the problem is in `main`.  The current code has this:

```
if ((memory = calloc(memsize, sizeof *memory)) == NULL)
        err(EXIT_FAILURE, NULL);
if ((fp = fopen(*argv, "r")) == NULL)
        err(EXIT_FAILURE, "%s", *argv);
```

The problem is that if the file doesn't exist, the memory just allocated will not be freed.  For that reason and for the fact that it's generally better to define variables when they are declared, I'd write that sequence like this instead:

```
FILE *fp = fopen(*argv, "r");
if (fp == NULL) {
    free(memory);
    err(EXIT_FAILURE, "%s", *argv);
}
```

### Think carefully about signed vs. unsigned numbers

What would it mean for the `memsize` to be a negative number?  I can't think of a rational interpretation for such a thing, so I'd recommend making that `size_t` which is unsigned.

### Eliminate global variables

In this case there lot of global variables such as `memory` and `memsize` which are probably better gathered up into a structure and made part of `main` instead of global.  Then for each of the relevant functions such as `load` or `dump`, pass a pointer to the structure as one of the arguments.

```
struct Simpletron {
    /* Simpletron's memory is simulated with a one-dimensional array */
    int *memory;
    size_t memsize;

    /* Simpletron's registers are simulated with the following variables */
    int acc;     /* accumulator register (value being processed) */
    size_t pc;   /* program counter points to current instruction */
    int opcode;  /* current opcode */
    int operand; /* current operand */
};
```

Note that I've also changed from `ireg` to `pc`.  More on that later.

### Make the program data driven

Instead of the `operation` `enum`, a large `switch` statement, etc. I think it would be much neater to have a `struct` for instructions.  Here's how I'd define it:

```
struct Instruction {
    int opcode;
    const char *mnemonic;
    const char *printstr;
    int (*exec)(struct Simpletron* s);
};
```

Now we can create an array of instructions.  Here's an example of one:

```
{ 52,"BRANCHZERO"," %2u", simple_instr_branchzero },
```

Now all that remains is to write the code that performs the instruction:

```
static int simple_instr_branchzero(struct Simpletron *s) {
    if (s->acc == 0) {
        s->pc = s->operand;
    } else {
        ++s->pc;
    }
    return WARN_NONE;
}
```

### Make error messages and numbers neater

You may have noticed that the function above returns `WARN_NONE`.  This is somewhat easier for a programmer to read and understand than something like `return 0` and also has the advantage that we now have both a code and a message (which might be translated to other languages, for instance).  So instead of this inside the large `switch`:

```
case ADD_I:
    if ((operand > 0 && acc > MEM_MAX - operand) ||
        (operand < 0 && acc < MEM_MIN - operand)) {
            warnx("integer overflow");
            return 1;
    } else {
            acc += operand;
    }
    count++;
    break;
```

We can write this:

```
static int simple_instr_add_i(struct Simpletron *s) {
    int result = s->acc + s->operand;
    if (isOutOfRange(result)) {
        return WARN_OVERFLOW;
    }
    s->acc = result;
    ++s->pc;
    return WARN_NONE;
}
```

This is enabled using this code:

```
enum warning { WARN_NONE, WARN_HALT, WARN_INPUT, WARN_OVERFLOW, WARN_DIVZERO, WARN_SIGNEDOVERFLOW, WARN_REMAINZERO, WARN_COUNT };
static const struct Error {
    enum warning value;
    const char *text;
} simpletron_errors[WARN_COUNT] = {
    { WARN_NONE, "ok" },
    { WARN_HALT, "halt" },
    { WARN_INPUT, "improper input" },
    { WARN_OVERFLOW, "integer overflow" },
    { WARN_DIVZERO, "division by zero" },
    { WARN_SIGNEDOVERFLOW, "signed integer overflow"},
    { WARN_REMAINZERO, "remainder by zero"},
};
```

Note that `WARN_COUNT` is not a real warning, but rather a marker to define the size of the array and also for us with error checking on access to that array.

### Use helper functions to clarify code

The code above uses `isOutOfRange` which simplifies the code and makes it clear to the reader.  The content is this:

```
static bool isOutOfRange(int n) {
    return n < MEM_MIN || n > MEM_MAX;
}
```

### Use action words for functions

The functions `load` and `dump` are named in a way that suggests their function, but I think `simpletron` is not as good.  Since they are all dealing with the same underlying machine, I'd suggest naming them as `simpletron_load`, `simpletron_dump` and `simpletron_run`.

### Separate interface from implementation

I'd suggest splitting the program into three pieces: `main.c` which would contain `main` and functions only needed by it, a `simpletron.h` file that defines the interface to the virtual machine and `simpletron.c` which would contain the implementation.  Here's how I would define `simpletron.h`:

```
#ifndef SIMPLETRON_H
#define SIMPLETRON_H
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

struct Simpletron {
    /* Simpletron's memory is simulated with a one-dimensional array */
    int *memory;
    size_t memsize;

    /* Simpletron's registers are simulated with the following variables */
    int acc;     /* accumulator register (value being processed) */
    size_t pc;   /* program counter points to current instruction */
    int opcode;  /* current opcode */
    int operand; /* current operand */
};

int simpletron_run(struct Simpletron *s, bool trace, bool verbose);
int simpletron_load(struct Simpletron *s, FILE *fp);
void simpletron_dump(struct Simpletron *s);
#endif // SIMPLETRON_H
```

Only the minimal information to use the interface is here.  All of the other details are encapsulated in `simpletron.c`.

### Prefer `const` to `#define`

Since C99, it's generally better to use `const` rather than `#define` for numerical constants.  For instance, I'd put these inside `simpletron.c`:

```
static const int MEM_MAX = 9999;
static const int MEM_MIN = -9999;
static const int INSTRUCTIONSIZE = 4;
```

This way, we get the benefit of type checking and also limiting scope.

### Consider adding features

I thought it would be nice to be able to trace the program and also, optionally, to dump the contents of the machine after each instruction.  This heavily modified version of your original `simpletron` function does just that.

```
/* run instructions from memory; return 1 if error occurs, return 0 otherwise */
int simpletron_run(struct Simpletron *s, bool trace, bool verbose) {
    /* memory location of next instruction */
    /* simulation begins with the instruction in the location 00 and continues sequentially */
    s->pc = 0;

    /* this loop implements the "instruction execution cycle" */
    while (s->pc < s->memsize) {
        /* opcode is the leftmost two digits of instruction register*/
        s->opcode = s->memory[s->pc] / 100;
        /* operand is the rightmost two digits of instruction register*/
        s->operand = s->memory[s->pc] % 100;
        /* simple linear scan for opcode */
        const struct Instruction *op = findop(s->opcode);
        if (op == NULL) {
            warnx("%+05d: invalid instruction", s->memory[s->pc]);
            return 1;
        }
        if (trace) {
            fprintf(stderr, "%05lu: %+05d\t", s->pc, s->memory[s->pc]);
            fprintf(stderr, op->mnemonic);
            fprintf(stderr, op->printstr, s->operand);
            fprintf(stderr, "\n");
        }
        int result = op->exec(s);
        if (verbose) {
            simpletron_dump(s);
        }
        if (result == WARN_HALT) {
            return 0;
        }
        if (result != WARN_NONE && result < WARN_COUNT) {
            warnx(simpletron_errors[result].text);
            return 1;
        }
    }
    warnx("execution reached end of memory without halting");
    return 1;
}
```

Using these features was a simple matter of adding the appropriate arguments for `main` and passing two boolean values.  Much of this functionality is enabled by the use of the data-driven design, but there's still more.

### Fully use data structures to simplify features

The posted example code purports to take an average of seven numbers, but it does no such thing.  In fact, it computes a sum of a list of numbers terminated by a sentinel value of zero.  A program that computes an average might look like this in source code form:

```
READ [13]   ; read a number from the uset
LOAD [13]   ; acc = number
ADD [15]    ; add to running sum
STORE [15]  ; store sum
LOAD [14]   ; fetch counter
ADD_I 1     ; increment by one
STORE [14]  ; save updated count
BRANCHNEG 0 ; if <0, we're not done yet
LOAD [15]   ; fetch the running sum
DIVIDE_I 7  ; divide by seven
STORE [13]  ; store the updated value
WRITE [13]  ; write it to stdout
HALT
+0000       ; this is location 13 used as a scratchpad for input
-0007       ; this is the value -n (number of numbers to avg)
+0000       ; this is location 15 that holds the running sum
```

It was certainly not obvious from a raw list of numbers what the original code actually did until I added the trace function mentioned above.  It's a relatively simple task to allow the code to accept either this nice source code version or the original raw number version.  Here's an enhanced `simpletron_load` function that does just that:

```
int simpletron_load(struct Simpletron *s, FILE *fp) {
    unsigned linenum = 1;
    char inst[13];
    inst[12] = '\0';  // assure it's terminated
    size_t i = 0;
    const char* error = NULL;
    while (!error && (fscanf(fp, "%12s", inst) == 1)) {
        // is it a number
        if (inst[0] == '+' || inst[0] == '-') {
            int arg;
            if (sscanf(inst, "%5d", &arg) == 1) {
                s->memory[i++] = arg;
            } else {
                error = "reading number";
            }
        } else {
            const struct Instruction *in = findmnemonic(inst);
            if (in) {
                if (strlen(in->printstr)) {
                    int arg = parsearg(in->printstr, fp);
                    if (arg >= 0) {
                        s->memory[i++] = in->opcode*100 + arg;
                    } else {
                        error = "reading instruction";
                    }
                } else {
                    s->memory[i++] = in->opcode*100;
                }
            } else {
                error = "reading instruction";
            }
        }
        // ignore the rest of the line
        for (int c = getc(fp); c != '\n' && c != EOF; c = getc(fp)) {
        }
        ++linenum;
        if (i >= s->memsize) {
            error = "memory full";
        }
    }
    if (error) {
        printf("ERROR:%s:%d\n", error, linenum);
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

### Make the machine do the counting

Rather than fiddling with tedious parsing of formatted output, I generally prefer to let the machine do the counting for me.  To that end, the rewritten `simpletron_dump` function now looks like this:

```
/* write a core dump of memory and registers into stdout */
void simpletron_dump(struct Simpletron *s) {
    const unsigned linelen = 10;
    fprintf(stderr, "\nREGISTERS:\n"
           "accumulator          %+05d\n"
           "instruction pointer  +%04lu\n"
           "\nMEMORY:\n  ",
           s->acc, s->pc);
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < linelen; ++i) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%7u", i);
    }
    unsigned dumpcount = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < s->memsize; ++i, --dumpcount) {
        if (dumpcount == 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "\n%2lu  ", i );
            dumpcount = linelen;
        }
        fprintf(stderr, "%+05d  ", s->memory[i]);
    }
    fprintf(stderr, "\n");
}
```

The code uses the `const unsigned linelen` to keep track of how many values to print out per line for both the header and for the memory dump.  That also fixes another bug in the original which did not print memory correctly.

### Understand real CPUs

I know this is all a learning exercise, but one thing that may be useful is to understand a bit more about real CPU architecture.  For example, rather than throwing an error in the event of overflow, real CPUs typically have a *carry flag* which indicates this and an *overflow flag* to indicate signed overflow.  Also, it is more typical to have an *instruction pointer* (sometimes called a *program counter*) rather than an instruction register that actually holds the current instruction.  Of course internal to the machine, something eventually does fetch and parse the value of the instruction, but it's quite rare for that to be directly accessible from the outside.  This was one reason I changed from `ireg` to `pc` as mentioned above.  It keeps things neater and more clearly mimics how real machines work.

### Results

Here's the revised version of `simpletron.c`:

````cpp
#include "simpletron.h"
#include <err.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <unistd.h>

static const int MEM_MAX = 9999;
static const int MEM_MIN = -9999;
static const int INSTRUCTIONSIZE = 4;

enum warning { WARN_NONE, WARN_HALT, WARN_INPUT, WARN_OVERFLOW, WARN_DIVZERO, WARN_SIGNEDOVERFLOW, WARN_REMAINZERO, WARN_COUNT };
static const struct Error {
    enum warning value;
    const char *text;
} simpletron_errors[WARN_COUNT] = {
    { WARN_NONE, "ok" },
    { WARN_HALT, "halt" },
    { WARN_INPUT, "improper input" },
    { WARN_OVERFLOW, "integer overflow" },
    { WARN_DIVZERO, "division by zero" },
    { WARN_SIGNEDOVERFLOW, "signed integer overflow"},
    { WARN_REMAINZERO, "remainder by zero"},
};

static bool isOutOfRange(int n) {
    return n < MEM_MIN || n > MEM_MAX;
}

/* get instruction from fp; return 0 if instruction is improper */
static int fetch_number(FILE *fp, int *instruction) {
    int num = 0;
    int c;
    int sign = 1;

    /* get initial blank */
    while (isblank(c = getc(fp)))
            ;

    /* get instruction/data sign */
    switch (c) {
        case '-':
            sign = -1;
            // fall through
        case '+':
            c = getc(fp);
            break;
        default:   // error condition
            return 0;
    }

    /* get instruction/data number */
    for (int i = INSTRUCTIONSIZE; i; --i) {
        if (!isdigit(c)) {  // error
            return 0;
        }
        num = num * 10 + c - '0';
        c = getc(fp);
    }

    /* get remaining of command line */
    while (c != '\n' && c != EOF) {
        c = getc(fp);
    }

    *instruction = sign * num;
    return 1;
}

static int simple_instr_read(struct Simpletron *s) {
    if (fetch_number(stdin, &s->memory[s->operand]) == 0) {
        return WARN_INPUT;
    }
    ++s->pc;
    return WARN_NONE;
}

static int simple_instr_write(struct Simpletron *s) {
    printf("%+05d\n", s->memory[s->operand]);
    ++s->pc;
    return WARN_NONE;
}
static int simple_instr_load(struct Simpletron *s) {
    s->acc = s->memory[s->operand];
    ++s->pc;
    return WARN_NONE;
}

static int simple_instr_store(struct Simpletron *s) {
    s->memory[s->operand] = s->acc;
    ++s->pc;
    return WARN_NONE;
}

static int simple_instr_add(struct Simpletron *s) {
    int result = s->acc + s->memory[s->operand];
    if (isOutOfRange(result)) {
        return WARN_OVERFLOW;
    }
    s->acc = result;
    ++s->pc;
    return WARN_NONE;
}

static int simple_instr_subtract(struct Simpletron *s) {
    int result = s->acc - s->memory[s->operand];
    if (isOutOfRange(result)) {
        return WARN_OVERFLOW;
    }
    s->acc = result;
    ++s->pc;
    return WARN_NONE;
}

static int simple_instr_divide(struct Simpletron *s) {
    if (s->memory[s->operand] == 0) {
        return WARN_DIVZERO;
    } else if ((s->acc == MEM_MIN) && (s->memory[s->operand] == -1)) {
        return WARN_SIGNEDOVERFLOW;
    } else {
        s->acc /= s->memory[s->operand];
    }
    ++s->pc;
    return WARN_NONE;
}

static int simple_instr_multiply(struct Simpletron *s) {
    s->acc *= s->memory[s->operand];
    if (isOutOfRange(s->acc)) {
        return WARN_OVERFLOW;
    }
    ++s->pc;
    return WARN_NONE;
}

static int simple_instr_remainder(struct Simpletron *s) {
    if (s->memory[s->operand] == 0) {
        return WARN_REMAINZERO;
    } else if ((s->acc == MEM_MIN) && (s->memory[s->operand] == -1)) {
        return WARN_SIGNEDOVERFLOW;
    } else {
        s->acc %= s->memory[s->operand];
    }
    ++s->pc;
    return WARN_NONE;
}

static int simple_instr_add_i(struct Simpletron *s) {
    int result = s->acc + s->operand;
    if (isOutOfRange(result)) {
        return WARN_OVERFLOW;
    }
    s->acc = result;
    ++s->pc;
    return WARN_NONE;
}

static int simple_instr_subtract_i(struct Simpletron *s) {
    int result = s->acc - s->operand;
    if (isOutOfRange(result)) {
        return WARN_OVERFLOW;
    }
    s->acc = result;
    ++s->pc;
    return WARN_NONE;
}

static int simple_instr_divide_i(struct Simpletron *s) {
    if (s->operand == 0) {
        return WARN_DIVZERO;
    } else if ((s->acc == MEM_MIN) && (s->operand == -1)) {
        return WARN_SIGNEDOVERFLOW;
    } else {
        s->acc /= s->operand;
    }
    ++s->pc;
    return WARN_NONE;
}

static int simple_instr_multiply_i(struct Simpletron *s) {
    s->acc *= s->operand;
    if (isOutOfRange(s->acc)) {
        return WARN_OVERFLOW;
    }
    ++s->pc;
    return WARN_NONE;
}

static int simple_instr_remainder_i(struct Simpletron *s) {
    if (s->operand == 0) {
        return WARN_REMAINZERO;
    } else if ((s->acc == MEM_MIN) && (s->operand == -1)){
        return WARN_SIGNEDOVERFLOW;
    } else {
        s->acc %= s->operand;
    }
    ++s->pc;
    return WARN_NONE;
}

static int simple_instr_branch(struct Simpletron *s) {
    s->pc = s->operand;
    return WARN_NONE;
}

static int simple_instr_branchneg(struct Simpletron *s) {
    if (s->acc < 0) {
        s->pc = s->operand;
    } else {
        ++s->pc;
    }
    return WARN_NONE;
}

static int simple_instr_branchzero(struct Simpletron *s) {
    if (s->acc == 0) {
        s->pc = s->operand;
    } else {
        ++s->pc;
    }
    return WARN_NONE;
}

static int simple_instr_halt(struct Simpletron *s) {
    s=s;
    return WARN_HALT;
}

static const struct Instruction {
    int opcode;
    const char *mnemonic;
    const char *printstr;
    int (*exec)(struct Simpletron* s);
} instructions[] = {
    { 10,"READ"," [%2u]", simple_instr_read },
    { 11,"WRITE"," [%2u]", simple_instr_write },
    { 20,"LOAD"," [%2u]", simple_instr_load },
    { 21,"STORE"," [%2u]", simple_instr_store },
    { 30,"ADD"," [%2u]", simple_instr_add },
    { 31,"SUBTRACT"," [%2u]", simple_instr_subtract },
    { 32,"DIVIDE"," [%2u]", simple_instr_divide },
    { 33,"MULTIPLY"," [%2u]", simple_instr_multiply },
    { 34,"REMAINDER"," [%2u]", simple_instr_remainder },
    { 40,"ADD_I"," %2u", simple_instr_add_i },
    { 41,"SUBTRACT_I"," %2u", simple_instr_subtract_i },
    { 42,"DIVIDE_I"," %2u", simple_instr_divide_i },
    { 43,"MULTIPLY_I"," %2u", simple_instr_multiply_i },
    { 44,"REMAINDER_I"," %2u", simple_instr_remainder_i },
    { 50,"BRANCH"," %2u", simple_instr_branch },
    { 51,"BRANCHNEG"," %2u", simple_instr_branchneg },
    { 52,"BRANCHZERO"," %2u", simple_instr_branchzero },
    { 53,"HALT","" , simple_instr_halt },

};

static const struct Instruction *findop(int opcode) {
    for (size_t i=0; i < sizeof(instructions)/sizeof(instructions[0]); ++i) {
        if (opcode == instructions[i].opcode) {
            return &instructions[i];
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}

static const struct Instruction *findmnemonic(const char *mnemonic) {
    for (size_t i=0; i < sizeof(instructions)/sizeof(instructions[0]); ++i) {
        if (strcmp(mnemonic, instructions[i].mnemonic) == 0) {
            return &instructions[i];
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}

/* run instructions from memory; return 1 if error occurs, return 0 otherwise */
int
simpletron_run(struct Simpletron *s, bool trace, bool verbose)
{
    /* memory location of next instruction */
    /* simulation begins with the instruction in the location 00 and continues sequentially */
    s->pc = 0;

    /* this loop implements the "instruction execution cycle" */
    while (s->pc < s->memsize) {
        /* opcode is the leftmost two digits of instruction register*/
        s->opcode = s->memory[s->pc] / 100;
        /* operand is the rightmost two digits of instruction register*/
        s->operand = s->memory[s->pc] % 100;
        /* simple linear scan for opcode */

        const struct Instruction *op = findop(s->opcode);
        if (op == NULL) {
            warnx("%+05d: invalid instruction", s->memory[s->pc]);
            return 1;
        }
        if (trace) {
            fprintf(stderr, "%05lu: %+05d\t", s->pc, s->memory[s->pc]);
            fprintf(stderr, op->mnemonic);
            fprintf(stderr, op->printstr, s->operand);
            fprintf(stderr, "\n");
        }
        int result = op->exec(s);
        if (verbose) {
            simpletron_dump(s);
        }
        if (result == WARN_HALT) {
            return 0;
        }
        if (result != WARN_NONE && result < WARN_COUNT) {
            warnx(simpletron_errors[result].text);
            return 1;
        }
    }
    warnx("execution reached end of memory without halting");
    return 1;
}

static int parsearg(const char *fmt, FILE *fp) {
    unsigned arg = 0;
    int result = fscanf(fp, fmt, &arg);
    return (result == 1) ? (int)arg : -1;
}

int simpletron_load(struct Simpletron *s, FILE *fp) {
    unsigned linenum = 1;
    char inst[13];
    inst[12] = '\0';  // assure it's terminated
    size_t i = 0;
    const char* error = NULL;
    while (!error && (fscanf(fp, "%12s", inst) == 1)) {
        // is it a number
        if (inst[0] == '+' || inst[0] == '-') {
            int arg;
            if (sscanf(inst, "%5d", &arg) == 1) {
                s->memory[i++] = arg;
            } else {
                error = "reading number";
            }
        } else {
            const struct Instruction *in = findmnemonic(inst);
            if (in) {
                if (strlen(in->printstr)) {
                    int arg = parsearg(in->printstr, fp);
                    if (arg >= 0) {
                        s->memory[i++] = in->opcode*100 + arg;
                    } else {
                        error = "reading instruction";
                    }
                } else {
                    s->memory[i++] = in->opcode*100;
                }
            } else {
                error = "reading instruction";
            }
        }
        // ignore the rest of the line
        for (int c = getc(fp); c != '\n' && c != EOF; c = getc(fp)) {
        }
        ++linenum;
        if (i >= s->memsize) {
            error = "memory full";
        }
    }
    if (error) {
        printf("ERROR:%s:%d\n", error, linenum);
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

/* write a core dump of memory and registers into stdout */
void simpletron_dump(struct Simpletron *s) {
    fprintf(stderr, "\nREGISTERS:\n"
           "accumulator          %+05d\n"
           "instruction pointer  +%04lu\n",
           s->acc, s->pc);
    fprintf(stderr, "\nMEMORY:\n  ");
    const unsigned linelen = 10;
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < linelen; ++i) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%7u", i);
    }
    unsigned dumpcount = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < s->memsize; ++i, --dumpcount) {
        if (dumpcount == 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "\n%2lu  ", i );
            dumpcount = linelen;
        }
        fprintf(stderr, "%+05d  ", s->memory[i]);
    }
    fprintf(stderr, "\n");
}
```
````

Comment: I am in fact too much adapted with old idioms I learned from K&R and manpages. Do you recommend any book I can read to make me adapt to the modern programming practices and idioms?

Comment: I would recommend  "Modern C" by Jens Gustedt.  It is a very recent book published by Manning and looks like an excellent resource for learning the modern version of the language.

Comment: _define variables when they are defined_ - you mean initialize when defined?

Comment: Yes, I meant *define variables when they are **declared***.  Corrected now, thanks!

Comment: For that conversion, I opened the file in two windows and cut and pasted the body of each `case` statement into each separate function.  Then just do minimal modifications for converting to use the `struct Simpletron` and you're done.  Tedious, perhaps, but not hard.  Let me know if I can answer any questions or help.

Comment: I have already done the `struct simpletron` thing, it's in the edition I linked to in my last comment. It was easy, the conversion of the case statements is what is exhausting me.

Answer (score 7):

### Re-entrance

These:

```
static int *memory;
static int acc;     /* accumulator register (value being processed) */
static int ireg;    /* instruction register (current instruction) */
// ...

    static int count;
    static int opcode;
    static int operand;
```

force a user to start a new program if they want a new instance of the calculator. If you want to offer an API that allows the co-existence of multiple calculators, pass around a struct instead.

### C99

These:

```
int c, exitval, coredump;
FILE *fp;
```

haven't needed declaration at the beginning of the function for 20-ish years. It's more legible for them to be declared and initialized closer to where they're actually being used in the function.

### Assignment-in-condition

About these various statements -

```
while ((c = getopt(argc, argv, "cm:")) != -1) {
if ((memory = calloc(memsize, sizeof *memory)) == NULL)
if ((fp = fopen(*argv, "r")) == NULL)
while (isblank(c = getc(fp)))
```

Don't, please. Expand this out so that the variable is assigned in its own statement. The above is confusing and error-prone, and has no performance gains. The only thing it's good for is code golf, which you aren't currently playing.

### Addition efficiency

```
        if ((memory[operand] > 0 && acc > MEM_MAX - memory[operand]) ||
            (memory[operand] < 0 && acc < MEM_MIN - memory[operand])) {
            warnx("integer overflow");
            return 1;
        }
        else
            acc += memory[operand];
```

can become something like

```
int sum = memory[operand] + acc;
if (sum > MEM_MAX || sum < MEM_MIN) {
    warnx("integer overflow");
    return 1;
}
acc = sum;
```

In other words: don't do the addition three times; do it once. The same applies to `SUBTRACT`.

### Order of operations

```
((acc == MEM_MIN) && (memory[operand] == -1))
```

doesn't require inner parens, due to operator precedence.

### Typo

`REMINDER` should be `REMAINDER`.

### Loop sanity

```
    size_t i;

    i = 0;
    while(getinstruction(fp, &instruction) && i < memsize)
        memory[i++] = instruction;
```

is better represented by

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < memsize; i++) {
    if (!getinstruction(fp, &instruction))
        break;
    memory[i] = instruction;
}
```

### Memory efficiency

Currently you're storing integers in 32 bits that, since they have values of less than 10,000, could fit in 16. Depending on your constraints - whether you're optimizing for execution speed or memory efficiency - you might want to change this. 16 bits might actually be slower on your architecture, but to be sure you'd want to profile. Also, if you ever plan on serializing the state of the machine into a file, you should use 16 bits (`int16_t` from `stdint.h`).

Comment: For the addition, I was using SEI's [CERT INT32-C](https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/c/INT32-C.+Ensure+that+operations+on+signed+integers+do+not+result+in+overflow) to ensure integer overflow.  The assignment-in-condition is a hint that survived from when I read K&R book, they use assignment-in-condition all the time. Declaration at the beginning of function was also from K&R.
I am reading Deitel's C:How to Program after have read K&R, is this a good path choice? I think Deitel's codes are much less elegant than K&R's...

Comment: Also, the assignments-in-condition (particularly the one for getopt(3)) are idioms I've learnt from OpenBSD's manpages. I think assignment-in-conditions are not out of fashion in operating system development cycles.

Comment: Re. K&R - the most recent (2nd) edition is from 1988. C99 should be used by everyone at this point. The classics are classic, but they need to be taken with a grain of salt and some understanding of the modern world.

Comment: _is this a good path choice?_ - It's difficult to say. Deitel apparently has an 8th edition from 2015 but I cannot speak to its contents. Generally speaking, I think that it's great for you to be working from textbooks, and it should be easy for you to pick up modern industry trends after.

Comment: _I was using SEI's CERT INT32-C to ensure integer overflow_ - it's excellent for you to be thinking about those details, but I fear that the situation is more complicated. Modern optimizing compilers are able to move terms across the sides of an inequality, for instance. That aside, since you're currently using a 32-bit representation, the data range is significantly narrower than the register range, so you do not have to worry about these details. Even if you switched to 16-bit, you would still be safe, because 2*10^4 < 2^15.

Comment: Also, it does not surprise me that man pages and operating system code both show signs of predating C99, since the BSD kernel certainly happened first, and it's entirely likely that it hasn't switched styles.

Comment: This program is from an exercise from Deitel's last book (8th edition). I am doing now its second part: a Simple Compiler (a compiler that translates a BASIC-like language into Simpletron Machine Language), it is VERY hard. After Deitel, I am thinking in going to «The Practice of Programming», by Kernighan and Rob Pike, and to «Modern C», and then to Sedgewick's «Algoritms in C» and «Advanced Programming in the UNIX Environment». I appreciate any opinions on this path I chose.

Comment: The extent of my textbook education in C is Yaroshenko's 1994 _Beginner's Guide to C++_; so in terms of book path I cannot offer any intelligent opinions. I think that, given the mix of textbook learning and verification on Stack Exchange, you will do just fine :)

Comment: Sounds like a job for `int16_fast_t`!