# Simple BASIC to Simpletron Machine Language compiler in C

Tags: c, compiler, basic-lang

I implemented a compiler that compiles a dialect of BASIC known as SimpleBASIC into Simpletron Machine Language to be run by the [Simpletron simulator](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/239425/simpletron-simulator-in-c).

I wrote the manual for the SimpleBASIC compiler in troff, it contains the commands of the SimpleBASIC language and some example programs.

```
simple(6)                       Games Manual                      simple(6)

NAME
       simple - compiles SimpleBASIC into Simple Machine Language

SYNOPSIS
       simple [-O] [-o outfile] infile

DESCRIPTION
       simple compiles a source code written in a dialect of BASIC known as
       SimpleBASIC into a program in Simple Machine Language (SML) ready to
       be run by the Simpletron simulator.

       A  file containing a SimpleBASIC program is read by the compiler and
       converted to SML code.  The SML code is output to a file on disk, in
       which SML instructions appear one per line.  This file is by default
       a.out, but can be set by the option -o.  The SML file  can  then  be
       loaded into the Simpletron simulator.

       The options are as follows:

       -O     Optimize the compilation.  Makes the compiler do another pass
              to get rid of redundant instructions.

       -o outfile
              Put executable program into output file outfile.

THE SIMPLEBASIC COMPILATOR
   The symbol table
       The symbol table is a table that  contains  each  symbol  (label  or
       variable)  in the program and its corresponding location in the Sim‐
       pletron's memory.  For a label, the location is the position in  the
       Simpletron memory where the SML instruction generated by the Simple‐
       BASIC statement begin.  For a variable, the location is the position
       in the Simpletron memory where the variable is stored.

       Each symbol (variable or label) is a single-character identifier.

   The SML array
       The  SML  array  contains  the Simpletron Machine Language (SML) in‐
       structions generated by the SimpleBASIC commands.  An  SML  instruc‐
       tion is a four-digit integer that comprises two parts: the operation
       code (opcode) and the operand.

       The opcode is determined by commands in  SimpleBASIC.  For  example,
       the SimpleBASIC command input correspond to SML opcode 11 (write).

       The operand is a immediate value or a memory location containing the
       data on which the operation code performs its  task.   For  example,
       the  opcode  10 (input) reads a value from keyboard and stores it in
       the memory location specified by the operand.  The compiler  searchs
       the  symbol  table  to  determine the Simpletron memory location for
       each symbol so the corresponding location can be  used  to  complete
       the SML instructions.

       Generaly,  each  SimpleBASIC command generates a single SML instruc‐
       tion.  But compilation of IF...GOTO and LET statements is more  com‐
       plicated  than  other  statements: they are the only statements that
       produce more than one SML instruction.

       For an IF...GOTO statement, the compiler produces code to  test  the
       condition and to branch to another line if necessary.  The result of
       the branch could be an unresolved reference.  Each of the relational
       and  quality  operators can be simulated using SML's branch zero and
       branch negative instructions (or possibly a combination of both).

       For a LET statement, the compiler produces code to evaluate an arbi‐
       trarily  complex  arithmetic  expression consisting of integer vari‐
       ables and/or constants.  When a compiler encounters  an  expression,
       it  converts the expression from infix notation to postfix notation,
       then evaluates the postfix expression.

   The flag array
       When a GOTO statement is compiled with an unresolved reference (ie',
       it refers to a location in the code that has not been read yet), the
       SML instruction must be flagged to indicate that the second pass  of
       the compiler must complete the instruction.  The flags are stored in
       an array of type char in which each element is initialized to  zero.
       If  the memory location to which a line number in the Simple program
       refers is not yet known (ie', it's not in  the  symbol  table),  the
       line number is stored in the flag array in the element with the same
       subscript as the incomplete instruction.  The operand of the  incom‐
       plete instruction is set to 00 temporarily.

       For  example,  an unconditional branch instruction (making a forward
       reference) is left as +5000 until the resolve pass of the compiler.

   Memory size
       The Simpletron machine contains only 100 locations of memory, and  a
       SML  program loaded into the Simpletron's machine occupies the whole
       memory.  Both data and instructions are located in memory.  The  be‐
       ginning  of  the memory is used to store instructions, while the end
       of the memory is used to store data.  The  position  of  the  memory
       where  the  next instruction and data should be placed is determined
       by the instruction counter and the the data counter, respectively.

   Counters
       It's necessary to keep track of the next instruction location in the
       SML  array  because there is not a one-to-one correspondence between
       SimpleBASIC statements and SML instructions.

       Each time an instruction is produced, the instruction counter is in‐
       cremented to the next location in the SML array.

       The  size  of Simpletron's memory could present a problem for Simple
       programs with many statements, variables and constants.   It's  con‐
       ceivable that the compiler will run out of memory.  To test for this
       case, the program contains a data counter to keep track of the loca‐
       tion  at  which  the next variable or constant will be stored in the
       SML array.

       If the value of the instruction counter  is  larger  than  the  data
       counter,  the  SML  array  is  full.   In this case, the compilation
       process terminates and the compiler prints an error message indicat‐
       ing that it ran out of memory during compilation.

   Passes
       The  compiler performs four passes (five, if optimization is set) to
       convert a SimpleBASIC program to SML.

       Initialize
              The zeroth pass initializates the compilation  variables  and
              arrays.   The  symbol table, the SML array and the flag array
              are allocated and initialized.  The compilation counters  are
              zeroed.

       Populate
              The  first  actual  pass  populate  the symbol table with the
              variable names and label names from the source code, populate
              the  SML array with instructions generated by the SimpleBASIC
              statements, and flag any instruction that is  incomplete  and
              needs another pass to be fully completed.

       Optimization
              This  pass  only  occurs  if the -O option is used.  It walks
              through the SML array in order to find sets of redundant  in‐
              structions and replace them with a single instruction.  When‐
              ever a redundant set of instructions is found, the  locations
              in the symbol table and the flags are ajusted to point to the
              new instruction.

       Resolve
              This pass resolves any  incomplete  instruction.   Incomplete
              instructions  have only the opcode, but does not have a oper‐
              and, and are flagged as  incomplete  by  the  populate  pass.
              When an instruction flagged as incomplete is found, this pass
              locate the symbol refered to by the flag array and insert the
              memory location from the symbol into the instruction with the
              unresolved reference.

       Assemble
              This pass walks through the SML array in order to  write  the
              instructions to a file.  This file is ready to be executed by
              the Simpletron simulator.  By default, this file  is  created
              as a.out, but this can be changed by the -o outfile option.

THE SIMPLEBASIC LANGUAGE
       SimpleBASIC  is  a simple, yet powerful, high level language similar
       to early versions of the popular language BASIC.

       Each line is a SimpleBASIC statement that consists of a command  and
       its  arguments.   Each command begins with one of the following key‐
       words.

              input
              let
              print
              goto
              if
              end

       Variable and label names are single-letter names.  SimpleBASIC  does
       not  allow  descriptive  variable  names, so variables should be ex‐
       plained in comments to indicate their use in the program.

       SimpleBASIC uses only integer variables.  Simple does not have vari‐
       able  declarations,  merely  mentioning a variable name in a program
       causes the variable to be declared and initialized to zero automati‐
       cally.

       The  syntax of SimpleBASIC does not allow string manipulation.  If a
       string is encountered in a SimpleBASIC command, the compiler  gener‐
       ates a syntax error.

       SimpleBASIC  uses the conditional IF...GOTO statement and the uncon‐
       ditional GOTO statement to alter the flow of control during  program
       execution.   If  the  condition  in the IF...GOTO statement is true,
       control is transferred to a specific line of the program.

       A comment in SimpleBASIC beggins with ; and go through  the  end  of
       line.

   Labels
       A label is any letter followed by a colon.  A label can occur before
       any SimpleBASIC statement.  Labels are used by transfer  of  control
       statements to implement flow of control and loops during process ex‐
       ecution.

   SimpleBASIC commands
       Commands in SimpleBASIC are case insensitive.  Both INPUT and  input
       are the same command.

       INPUT  A  input  statement  prompts the user to enter an integer and
              assign it to a variable.  For example, the  following  state‐
              ment reads an integer from the keyboard and stores that inte‐
              ger in x.

              INPUT x

       LET    A let statement assign the value of an expression to a  vari‐
              able.   For  example,  the  following  statement assign u the
              value of 4 * (j - 56).  An arbitarily complex expression  can
              appear to the right of the equal sign.  SimpleBASIC evaluates
              only integer expressions using the +, -, *, /  and  %  opera‐
              tors.  These  operators  have  the  same  precedence as in C.
              Parentheses can be used to change the order of evaluation  of
              an expression.

              LET u = 4 * (j - 56)

       PRINT  A  print  statement display the value of a previously defined
              variable.  For example, the following statement  display  the
              value of w.

              PRINT w

       GOTO   A  goto  statement  transfer program control to the statement
              after a specified label in the source code.  For example, the
              following  statement  transfer control to the statement after
              the label a.

              GOTO a

       IF ... GOTO
              A if...goto statement compare two variables and transfer pro‐
              gram  control to the label specified after GOTO if the condi‐
              tion is true; otherwise, continue  execution  with  the  next
              statement.   The  following relational and equality operators
              are valid in an IF...GOTO statement: <, >, <=, >=, == or  !=.
              For  example,  the  following  statement  compare i and z for
              equality and transfer program control to label j if they  are
              equal.

              IF i == z GOTO j

       end    A end statement terminate program execution.  For example

              END

EXAMPLES
   add.basic
       The  following  program reads two integers from the keyboard, stores
       the values in variables a and b, and computes and prints  their  sum
       (stored in variable c).

              ; determine and print the sum of two integers

              ; input two integers
              INPUT a
              INPUT b

              ; add integers and store result in c
              LET c = a + b

              ; print the result
              PRINT c

              ; terminate program execution
              END

   larger.basic
       The  following program determines and prints the larger of two inte‐
       gers.  The integers are input from the keyboard and stored in s  and
       t.  The IF...GOTO statement tests the condition s >= t.  If the con‐
       dition is true, control is transferred to label a and s  is  output;
       otherwise,  t is output and control is transferred to the END state‐
       ment in label

              ; determine the larger of two integers

              INPUT s
              INPUT t

              ; test if s >= t
              IF s >= t GOTO a

              ; t is greater than s, so print t
              PRINT t
              GOTO b

              ; s is greater than or equal to t, so print s
              a:
              PRINT s

              b:
              END

   square.basic
       SimpleBASIC does not provide a repetition  structure  (such  as  C's
       for,  while  or do...while).  However, SimpleBASIC can simulate each
       of C's repetition structures using the  IF...GOTO  and  GOTO  state‐
       ments.

       The  following  program uses a sentinel-controlled loop to calculate
       the squares of several integers.  Each integer  is  input  from  the
       keyboard and stored in variable j.  If the value entered is the sen‐
       tinel +0000, control is transfered to END, where the program  termi‐
       nates.  Otherwise, k is assigned the square of j, k is output to the
       screen and control is passed to where the next integer is input.

              ; Calculate the squares of several integers

              a:
              INPUT j

              ; set i as the sentinel value
              LET i = +0000

              ; test for sentinel value
              IF j == i GOTO b

              ; calculate square of j and assign result to k
              LET k = j * j
              PRINT k

              ; loop to get next j
              GOTO a

              b:
              END

EXIT STATUS
       0      Success.

       >0     Error occurred.

HISTORY
       This version of simple, the SimpleBASIC compiler, is  based  on  the
       exercises  12.26~12.28  from  the [Build Your Own Compiler] pdf pro‐
       vided by Deitel.

       The line label system is unique to this  implementation,  since  the
       exercise  use  line  number system as the target of GOTO statements.
       For more information, see the Wikipedia pages on [Line  Number]  and
       [Line Label].

CAVEATS
       This version of simple supports only variables in IF statements.  It
       does not support expressions or constants in IF statements.

       This version of simple only supports single-letter  symbols.   In  a
       next  version,  I  will  replace the symbol table by a binary search
       tree and implement multi-letter symbols.

       It also does not support immediate operands for instructions.

SEE ALSO
       simpletron(6)

       [Build Your Own Compiler]
              https://web.archive.org/web/20190819021934/http://www.deitel.com/bookresources/chtp8/CompilerExercises.pdf

       [Line number]
              https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_number

       [Line label]
              https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_label

       [Deitel & Deitel]
              C:  How to Program (8th edition), Paul Deitel and Harvey Dei‐
              tel

                                                                  simple(6)
```

Here is simple.h

```
#define MEMSIZE   100
#define TOKENSIZE 63

typedef int16_t memtype;

enum tokentype {
    COMMENT,
    RELATIONAL,
    ARITHMETIC,
    ASSIGNMENT,
    GOTOKEYWRD,
    VARIABLE,
    EXPRESSION,
    LABEL,
    NEWLINE,
    COMMAND
};

enum operation {
    READ       = 10,
    WRITE      = 11,
    LOAD       = 20,
    STORE      = 21,
    ADD        = 30,
    SUBTRACT   = 31,
    DIVIDE     = 32,
    MULTIPLY   = 33,
    REMINDER   = 34,
    ADD_I      = 40,
    SUBTRACT_I = 41,
    DIVIDE_I   = 42,
    MULTIPLY_I = 43,
    REMINDER_I = 44,
    BRANCH     = 50,
    BRANCHNEG  = 51,
    BRANCHZERO = 52,
    HALT       = 53
};

struct symbol {
    enum {
        label,
        variable,
        none
    } type;
    size_t location;
};

struct expression {
    enum {
        symb,
        num,
        op
    } type;
    union {
        memtype n;
        char c;
    } u;
    struct expression *next;
};

struct compiler {
    size_t memsize;
    struct symbol *symtable; /* the symbol table */
    memtype *sml;            /* the sml instructions */
    char *flag;              /* the flag array */
    char *file;              /* name of file to be compiled*/
    size_t ln;               /* current line of file to be compiled */
    size_t inscount;
    size_t datacount;
};

typedef void (*instruction)(struct compiler *);
```

Here is simple.c

```
#include <err.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include "simple.h"

static char *tokenstring[] = {
    [COMMENT] = "comment",
    [RELATIONAL] = "relational operator",
    [ARITHMETIC] = "arithmetic operator",
    [ASSIGNMENT] = "equal sign",
    [GOTOKEYWRD] = "goto keyword",
    [VARIABLE] = "variable",
    [EXPRESSION] = "expression",
    [LABEL] = "label",
    [NEWLINE] = "newline",
    [COMMAND] = "command"
};

/* compilation passes */
static void initialize(struct compiler *, char *);
static void populate(struct compiler *);
static void optimize(struct compiler *);
static void resolve(struct compiler *);
static void assemble(struct compiler, char *);

/* grammatical functions */
static char *gettoken(struct compiler *, enum tokentype, enum tokentype *);

/* functions to generate machine instructions */
static void command_input(struct compiler *);
static void command_let(struct compiler *);
static void command_print(struct compiler *);
static void command_goto(struct compiler *);
static void command_if(struct compiler *);
static void command_end(struct compiler *);
static instruction iscommand(char *);

/* symbol table manipulation functions */
static struct symbol *inserttable(struct compiler *, char, int, size_t);
static struct symbol *searchtable(struct compiler *, char);

/* expression handler functions */
static struct expression *getexpr(struct compiler *, char *s);
static int isoperator(char c);
static void enqueue(struct expression **head, struct expression **tail, struct expression operand);

/* usage */
static void usage(void);

/* simpleBASIC to Simpletron Machine Language compiler */
int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    struct compiler comp;
    int c;
    char *out = "a.out";
    bool dooptimize;

    dooptimize = false;
    while ((c = getopt(argc, argv, "Oo:")) != -1) {
        switch (c) {
        case 'O':
            dooptimize = true;
            break;
        case 'o':
            out = optarg;
            break;
        default:
            usage();
            break;
        }
    }
    argc -= optind;
    argv += optind;

    if (argc != 1)
        usage();

    initialize(&comp, *argv);
    populate(&comp);
    if (dooptimize)
        optimize(&comp);
    resolve(&comp);
    assemble(comp, out);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

/* initialize symbol table, instruction array, flag array and counters */
static void
initialize(struct compiler *comp, char *filename)
{
    static struct symbol symtable['z' - 'A'];
    static memtype sml[MEMSIZE];
    static char flag[MEMSIZE];
    size_t i;

    comp->symtable = symtable;
    comp->sml = sml;
    comp->flag = flag;
    comp->memsize = MEMSIZE;
    comp->file = filename;
    comp->ln = 1;
    comp->inscount = 0;
    comp->datacount = comp->memsize - 1;

    /* initialize arrays */
    for (i = 'A'; i < 'z'; i++)
        symtable[i - 'A'].type = none;
    for (i = 0; i < comp->memsize; i++)
        flag[i] = '\0';
}

/* populate symbol table, instruction array, and flag array */
static void
populate(struct compiler *comp)
{
    enum tokentype toktype;
    char *tok;

    /* while there is a command, generate instructions for it */
    while ((tok = gettoken(comp, COMMAND, &toktype)) != NULL) {

        /* ignore comments */
        if (toktype == COMMENT)
            continue;

        /* if command is a label declaration, put it in symbol table */
        if (toktype == LABEL) {
            if (searchtable(comp, *tok) != NULL) {
                fprintf(stderr, "%s:%lu: error: redeclaration of '%c'\n",
                        comp->file, comp->ln, *tok);
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            inserttable(comp, *tok, label, comp->inscount);
            continue;
        }

        /* generate instructions for statement */
        (*iscommand(tok))(comp);

        /* get obligatory newline after statement */
        gettoken(comp, NEWLINE, &toktype);

        /* if instructions overlap data, compilation run out of memory */
        if (comp->inscount > comp->datacount)
            errx(1, "compilation ran out of memory");
    }
}

/* optimize compilation by getting rid of redundant instructions */
static void
optimize(struct compiler *comp)
{
    memtype opcode0, opcode1, opcode2;  /* current, next and nextnext opcode */
    memtype operand0, operand1;         /* current and next operand */
    size_t i, j;

    for (i = 0; i < comp->inscount; i++) {
        opcode0  = comp->sml[i] / comp->memsize;
        operand0 = comp->sml[i] % comp->memsize;
        opcode1  = comp->sml[i+1] / comp->memsize;
        operand1 = comp->sml[i+1] % comp->memsize;
        opcode2 = comp->sml[i+2] / comp->memsize;

        if (operand0 == operand1 && opcode2 == STORE
            && opcode0 == STORE && opcode1 == LOAD) {
            for (j = 0; j < 'z' - 'A'; j++)
                if (comp->symtable[j].type == label && comp->symtable[j].location > i)
                    comp->symtable[j].location -= 2;
            for (j = i; j < comp->inscount; j++) {
                comp->sml[j] = comp->sml[j + 2];
                comp->flag[j] = comp->flag[j + 2];
            }
        }

    }
}

/* resolve memory locations flagged as incomplete */
static void
resolve(struct compiler *comp)
{
    struct symbol *sym;
    size_t i;

    /* traverse flag array looking for flagged memory locations */
    for (i = 0; i < comp->memsize; i++) {
        if (comp->flag[i] != '\0') {
            sym = searchtable(comp, comp->flag[i]);
            if (sym == NULL)
                errx(1, "failed to find label %c", comp->flag[i]);
            if (sym->type != label)
                errx(1, "failed to find label %c", comp->flag[i]);
            comp->sml[i] += sym->location;
        }
    }
}

/* write machine code in memory to file */
static void
assemble(struct compiler comp, char *file)
{
    FILE *fp;
    size_t i;

    if ((fp = fopen(file, "w")) == NULL)
        err(EXIT_FAILURE, "%s", file);

    for (i = 0; i < comp.memsize; i++)
        fprintf(fp, "%+05d\n", comp.sml[i]);

    if (ferror(fp))
        err(1, "%s", file);
    fclose(fp);

}

/*
 * Get next token from fp, and return a pointer to it (or NULL if EOF is found).
 * expected is the type of expected token, *got is the type of got token.
 * If expected and *got are different, exit with error, except when expected a
 * command and got a label definition.
 */
static char *
gettoken(struct compiler *comp, enum tokentype expected, enum tokentype *got)
{
    instruction inst;
    static char s[TOKENSIZE];
    static FILE *fp = NULL;
    int c;
    size_t i;

    if (fp == NULL) {
        fp = fopen(comp->file, "r");
        if (fp == NULL)
            err(EXIT_FAILURE, "%s", comp->file);
    }

    /* get blank on the beginning */
    while (isblank(c = getc(fp)))
        ;

    i = 0;

    /* consider blank lines as remarks */
    if (expected == COMMAND && c == '\n') {
        s[i] = ';';
        s[i++] = '\0';
        comp->ln++;
        *got = COMMENT;
    } else if (expected == EXPRESSION) {   /* if expected expression, get remaining of line */
        while (c != '\n' && i < TOKENSIZE - 1) {
            s[i++] = c;
            c = getc(fp);
        }
        if (c != '\n') {
            fprintf(stderr, "%s:%lu: error: expression too long\n", comp->file, comp->ln);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        ungetc(c, fp);
        s[i] = '\0';
        *got = EXPRESSION;
    } else if (c == '\n') {         /* because newline is a token */
        s[i++] = c;
        s[i] = '\0';
        *got = NEWLINE;
    } else if (c == ';') {          /* comment */
        s[i++] = c;
        s[i] = '\0';
        while (c != '\n')
            c = getc(fp);
        comp->ln++;
        *got = COMMENT;
    } else if (c == '=') {          /* test if it's = or == */
        s[i++] = c;

        c = getc(fp);
        if (c == '=') {
            s[i++] = c;
            *got = RELATIONAL;
        } else {
            ungetc(c, fp);
            *got = ASSIGNMENT;
        }
        s[i] = '\0';
    } else if (c == '!') {          /* token is != */
        s[i++] = c;
        c = getc(fp);
        if (c != '=') {
            fprintf(stderr, "%s:%lu: error: unexpected character '%c'\n",
                    comp->file, comp->ln, c);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        s[i++] = c;
        s[i] = '\0';
        *got = RELATIONAL;
    } else if (c == '<' || c == '>') {     /* token is <, >, <= or >= */
        s[i++] = c;
        c = getc(fp);
        if (c == '=')
            s[i++] = c;
        else
            ungetc(c, fp);
        s[i] = '\0';
        *got = RELATIONAL;
    } else if (isoperator(c)) {     /* token is operator */
        s[i++] = c;
        s[i] = '\0';
        *got = ARITHMETIC;
    } else if (isalpha(c)) {        /* token is command, variable or label */
        do {
            s[i++] = c;
            c = getc(fp);
        } while (isalpha(c) && i < TOKENSIZE - 1);
        s[i] = '\0';
        if (isalpha(c)) {
            fprintf(stderr, "%s:%lu: error: token too long\n", comp->file, comp->ln);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        if (c == ':') {
            *got = LABEL;
            while (isblank(c = getc(fp)))
                ;
            if (c != '\n')
                ungetc(c, fp);
        } else if ((inst = iscommand(s)) != NULL) {
            ungetc(c, fp);
            if (expected == GOTOKEYWRD && inst == command_goto)
                *got = GOTOKEYWRD;
            else
                *got = COMMAND;
        } else {
            ungetc(c, fp);
            if (expected == LABEL)
                *got = LABEL;
            else
                *got = VARIABLE;
        }
    } else if (c == EOF) {      /* close file after reading it */
        fclose(fp);
        return NULL;
    } else {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s:%lu: error: unexpected character '%c'\n", comp->file, comp->ln, c);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (ferror(fp))
        err(1, "%s", comp->file);

    /* if got a newline, increment line count */
    if (*s == '\n')
        comp->ln++;

    /* test whether you got what you expected (except for labels) */
    if (expected != *got) {
        if (expected != COMMAND || (*got != LABEL && *got != COMMENT)) {
            fprintf(stderr, "%s:%lu: error: %s expected (got %s)\n",
                    comp->file, comp->ln, tokenstring[expected], tokenstring[*got]);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }

    return s;
}

/* generate machine instructions for let statement */
static void
command_let(struct compiler *comp)
{
    struct symbol *sym;
    char *tok;
    enum tokentype toktype;
    size_t *stack, stacksize;
    size_t var, i;
    struct expression *expr;

    /* get location of variable to be assigned by let statement */
    tok = gettoken(comp, VARIABLE, &toktype);   /* get variable symbol */
    sym = searchtable(comp, *tok);              /* search in symbol table*/
    if (sym == NULL)                            /* if not found, insert it*/
        sym = inserttable(comp, *tok, variable, comp->datacount--);
    var = sym->location;

    /* get equal sign */
    tok = gettoken(comp, ASSIGNMENT, &toktype);

    /* get expression to assign and stack of addresses */
    tok = gettoken(comp, EXPRESSION, &toktype);
    expr = getexpr(comp, tok);
    stacksize = strlen(tok);
    stack = calloc(stacksize, sizeof *stack);

    /* generate machine instructions */
    i = 0;
    while (i < stacksize && expr != NULL) {
        size_t op1, op2;
        struct expression *tmp;

        if (expr->type == num) {
            comp->sml[comp->datacount] = expr->u.n;
            stack[i++] = comp->datacount--;
        } else if (expr->type == symb) {
            if ((sym = searchtable(comp, expr->u.c)) == NULL) /* if symbol not found, insert it*/
                sym = inserttable(comp, expr->u.c, variable, comp->datacount--);
            stack[i++] = sym->location;
        } else {
            if (i < 2) {
                fprintf(stderr, "%s:%lu error improper expression '%s'\n",
                        comp->file, comp->ln, tok);
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            op2 = stack[--i];
            op1 = stack[--i];
            comp->sml[comp->inscount++] = LOAD * MEMSIZE + op1;
            if (expr->u.c == '+')
                comp->sml[comp->inscount++] = ADD * MEMSIZE + op2;
            if (expr->u.c == '-')
                comp->sml[comp->inscount++] = SUBTRACT * MEMSIZE + op2;
            if (expr->u.c == '*')
                comp->sml[comp->inscount++] = MULTIPLY * MEMSIZE + op2;
            if (expr->u.c == '/')
                comp->sml[comp->inscount++] = DIVIDE * MEMSIZE + op2;
            if (expr->u.c == '%')
                comp->sml[comp->inscount++] = REMINDER * MEMSIZE + op2;
            comp->sml[comp->inscount++] = STORE * MEMSIZE + comp->datacount;
            stack[i++] = comp->datacount--;
        }
        tmp = expr;
        expr = expr->next;
        free(tmp);
    }
    if (i == 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s:%lu error improper expression '%s'\n",
                comp->file, i, tok);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    comp->sml[comp->inscount++] = LOAD * MEMSIZE + stack[--i];
    comp->sml[comp->inscount++] = STORE * MEMSIZE + var;
}

/* generate machine instructions for input statement */
static void
command_input(struct compiler *comp)
{
    char *tok;
    enum tokentype toktype;
    struct symbol *sym;

    /* get location of variable to be input */
    tok = gettoken(comp, VARIABLE, &toktype);   /* get variable name */
    sym = searchtable(comp, *tok);              /* search in symbol table */
    if (sym == NULL)                            /* if not found, insert it*/
        sym = inserttable(comp, *tok, variable, comp->datacount--);

    /* generate machine instruction */
    comp->sml[comp->inscount++] = READ * MEMSIZE + sym->location;
}

/* generate machine instructions for print statement */
static void
command_print(struct compiler *comp)
{
    char *tok;
    enum tokentype toktype;
    struct symbol *sym;

    /* get location of variable to print */
    tok = gettoken(comp, VARIABLE, &toktype);   /* get variable name */
    sym = searchtable(comp, *tok);              /* search in symbol table */
    if (sym == NULL) {                          /* if not found, it's an error */
        fprintf(stderr, "%s:%lu: error: '%c' undeclared\n",
                comp->file, comp->ln, *tok);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /* generate machine instruction */
    comp->sml[comp->inscount++] = WRITE * MEMSIZE + sym->location;
}

/* generate machine instructions for goto statement */
static void
command_goto(struct compiler *comp)
{
    char *tok;
    enum tokentype toktype;
    struct symbol *sym;
    size_t labeladdr;

    /* get location to go to */
    labeladdr = 0;
    tok = gettoken(comp, LABEL, &toktype);      /* get label name */
    sym = searchtable(comp, *tok);              /* search in symbol table */
    if (sym == NULL)                            /* if label not found, flag it*/
        comp->flag[comp->inscount] = *tok;
    else                                        /* if label is found, set it */
        labeladdr = sym->location;

    /* generate machine instruction */
    comp->sml[comp->inscount++] = BRANCH * MEMSIZE + labeladdr;
}

/* generate machine instructions for if statement */
static void
command_if(struct compiler *comp)
{
    char *tok;
    char relop[3];      /* relational operator */
    enum tokentype toktype;
    struct symbol *sym;
    size_t op1, op2, labeladdr;

    /* get location of first variable */
    tok = gettoken(comp, VARIABLE, &toktype);   /* get variable */
    sym = searchtable(comp, *tok);              /* search in symbol table */
    if (sym == NULL)                            /* if not found, insert it*/
        sym = inserttable(comp, *tok, variable, comp->datacount--);
    op1 = sym->location;

    /* get relational operator */
    tok = gettoken(comp, RELATIONAL, &toktype);
    strncpy(relop, tok, 2);
    relop[3] = '\0';

    /* get location of second variable */
    tok = gettoken(comp, VARIABLE, &toktype);   /* get variable */
    sym = searchtable(comp, *tok);              /* search in symbol table */
    if (sym == NULL)                            /* if not found, insert it*/
        sym = inserttable(comp, *tok, variable, comp->datacount--);
    op2 = sym->location;

    /* get obligatory 'goto' keyword */
    tok = gettoken(comp, GOTOKEYWRD, &toktype);

    /* get address of label to go to */
    labeladdr = 0;
    tok = gettoken(comp, LABEL, &toktype);      /* get label */
    sym = searchtable(comp, *tok);              /* search in symbol table */
    if (sym != NULL)                            /* if label is found, set it */
        labeladdr = sym->location;

    /* generate instructions based on branch type */
    if (strcmp(relop, "==") == 0) {
        comp->sml[comp->inscount++] = LOAD * MEMSIZE + op1;
        comp->sml[comp->inscount++] = SUBTRACT * MEMSIZE + op2;
        comp->sml[comp->inscount++] = BRANCHZERO * MEMSIZE + labeladdr;
    } else if (strcmp(relop, "!=") == 0) {
        comp->sml[comp->inscount++] = LOAD * MEMSIZE + op1;
        comp->sml[comp->inscount++] = SUBTRACT * MEMSIZE + op2;
        comp->sml[comp->inscount++] = BRANCHZERO * MEMSIZE + 2;
        comp->sml[comp->inscount++] = BRANCH * MEMSIZE + labeladdr;
    } else if (strcmp(relop, "<") == 0) {
        comp->sml[comp->inscount++] = LOAD * MEMSIZE + op1;
        comp->sml[comp->inscount++] = SUBTRACT * MEMSIZE + op2;
        comp->sml[comp->inscount++] = BRANCHNEG * MEMSIZE + labeladdr;
    } else if (strcmp(relop, ">") == 0) {
        comp->sml[comp->inscount++] = LOAD * MEMSIZE + op2;
        comp->sml[comp->inscount++] = SUBTRACT * MEMSIZE + op1;
        comp->sml[comp->inscount++] = BRANCHNEG * MEMSIZE + labeladdr;
    } else if (strcmp(relop, "<=") == 0) {
        comp->sml[comp->inscount++] = LOAD * MEMSIZE + op1;
        comp->sml[comp->inscount++] = SUBTRACT * MEMSIZE + op2;
        comp->sml[comp->inscount++] = BRANCHNEG * MEMSIZE + labeladdr;
        comp->sml[comp->inscount++] = BRANCHZERO * MEMSIZE + labeladdr;
    } else if (strcmp(relop, ">=") == 0) {
        comp->sml[comp->inscount++] = LOAD * MEMSIZE + op2;
        comp->sml[comp->inscount++] = SUBTRACT * MEMSIZE + op1;
        comp->sml[comp->inscount++] = BRANCHNEG * MEMSIZE + labeladdr;
        comp->sml[comp->inscount++] = BRANCHZERO * MEMSIZE + labeladdr;
    } else {
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /*
     * this checking must go after generating the instructions,
     * for it needs the variable inscount to be modified.
     */
    if (sym == NULL)                            /* if label not found, flag it */
        comp->flag[comp->inscount-1] = *tok;

}

/* generate machine instructions for end statement */
static void
command_end(struct compiler *comp)
{

    comp->sml[comp->inscount++] = HALT * MEMSIZE + 0;
}

/* return type of command s */
static instruction
iscommand(char *s)
{
    if (strcasecmp(s, "INPUT") == 0)
        return command_input;
    if (strcasecmp(s, "PRINT") == 0)
        return command_print;
    if (strcasecmp(s, "LET") == 0)
        return command_let;
    if (strcasecmp(s, "GOTO") == 0)
        return command_goto;
    if (strcasecmp(s, "IF") == 0)
        return command_if;
    if (strcasecmp(s, "END") == 0)
        return command_end;

    return NULL;
}

/* search for symbol in symbol table */
static struct symbol *
searchtable(struct compiler *comp, char c)
{
    if (comp->symtable[c - 'A'].type != none)
        return comp->symtable + c - 'A';

    return NULL;
}

/* insert symbol in symbol table */
static struct symbol *
inserttable(struct compiler *comp, char c, int type, size_t loc)
{
    if (comp->symtable[c - 'A'].type != none)
        return NULL;

    comp->symtable[c - 'A'].type = type;
    comp->symtable[c - 'A'].location = loc;
    return comp->symtable + c - 'A';
}

/* Convert infix expression in s into postfix expression in *expr list */
struct expression *
getexpr(struct compiler *comp, char *s)
{
    struct expression *head, *tail;
    char *stack, *endp;
    long n;
    int i;

    head = tail = NULL;
    stack = endp = NULL;
    i = 0;

    if ((stack = malloc(strlen(s) + 1)) == NULL)
        err(1, NULL);

    while (*s != '\0') {

        while (isspace(*s))
            s++;

        if (isalpha(*s)) {
            enqueue(&head, &tail, (struct expression) {.type = symb, .u.c = *s});
        } else if (isdigit(*s) || ((*s == '+' || *s == '-') && isdigit(s[1]))) {
            n = strtol(s, &endp, 10);
            if (n > INT_MAX || n < INT_MIN || endp == s) {
                fprintf(stderr, "%s:%lu: error: integer to big\n",
                        comp->file, comp->ln);
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            enqueue(&head, &tail, (struct expression) {.type = num, .u.n = n});
        } else if (*s == '(') {
            stack[i++] = '(';
        } else if (*s == ')') {
            while (i > 0 && isoperator(stack[i-1])) {
                i--;
                enqueue(&head, &tail, (struct expression) {.type = op, .u.c = stack[i]});
            }
            if (i > 0 && stack[i-1] == '(')
                i--;
        } else if (isoperator(*s)) {
            while (i > 0 && isoperator(stack[i-1])
                   && isoperator(stack[i-1]) >= isoperator(*s)) {
                i--;
                enqueue(&head, &tail, (struct expression) {.type = op, .u.c = stack[i]});
            }
            stack[i++] = *s;
        } else {
            fprintf(stderr, "%s:%lu: error: unexpected character '%c'\n",
                    comp->file, comp->ln, *s);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        s++;
    }
    while (i > 0 && isoperator(stack[i-1])) {
        i--;
        enqueue(&head, &tail, (struct expression) {.type = op, .u.c = stack[i]});
    }
    free(stack);
    return head;
}

/* return precedence of operator c, or 0 if it is not an operator */
static int
isoperator(char c)
{
    switch (c) {
    case '+': case '-':
        return 1;
    case '/': case '*': case '%':
        return 2;
    default:
        break;
    }
    return 0;
}

/* enqueue an operand or operator (op) into the expression list */
static void
enqueue(struct expression **head, struct expression **tail, struct expression op)
{
    struct expression *p;

    if ((p = malloc(sizeof *p)) == NULL)
        err(1, NULL);

    p->type = op.type;
    if (p->type == num)
        p->u.n = op.u.n;
    else
        p->u.c = op.u.c;
    p->next = NULL;

    if (*head == NULL)
        *head = p;
    else
        (*tail)->next = p;
    *tail = p;
}

static void
usage(void)
{
    (void) fprintf(stderr, "usage: simple [-O] [-o file.sml] file.simp\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

Here is a sample program in the SimpleBASIC language, sum.basic, it receives an integer (in the format of a Simpletron instruction) and outputs the sum of each number from 1 to the value entered.

```
; Sum 1 to x

INPUT x

; check y == x
a: IF  y == x GOTO e

; increment y
LET y = y + 1

; ADD y to total
LET t = t + y

; loop y
GOTO a

; output result
e:
PRINT t
END
```

The input of a Simpletron program must be a signed four-digit integer, like `+0007` or `-0001`.

Comment: `[COMMENT] = "comment"` - what the heck is happening here? Is this some way of specifying the index of assignment for an array initializer?

Comment: `COMMENT` is `0`, it is defined in `enum tokentype`. The array `tokenstring` is initialized with the values in `enum tokentype`. The array is used by the function `gettoken` to generate error strings when the got token is different from the expected token. For example, when the compiler expects a variable name but gets a comment, it prints `"%s expected (got %s)", tokenstring[VARIABLE], tokenstring[COMMENT]`

Comment: _The array tokenstring is initialized with the values in enum tokentype_ - right; specifically I'm unfamiliar with the brackets-on-the-LHS syntax.

Comment: An array can be initialized with the elements 2 and 4 specified as `int my_array[5] = { [2] = 5, [4] = 9 };`. It is equivalent to `int my_array[5] = { 0, 0, 5, 0, 9 };`. That's a C99 thing, I think.

Comment: Neat :) I don't pretend to know the whole standard; that's useful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### C99, assignment-in-conditions

At the risk of sounding like a broken record - I'll make the same recommendations as in [Simpletron simulator in C](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/239425/simpletron-simulator-in-c) . Consider moving your variable declarations closer to where they're used, and expanding out your assignment-in-condition statements.

There's another benefit to C99: this -

```
comp->symtable = symtable;
comp->sml = sml;
comp->flag = flag;
comp->memsize = MEMSIZE;
comp->file = filename;
comp->ln = 1;
comp->inscount = 0;
comp->datacount = comp->memsize - 1;
```

could be converted to a `const static` structure instance using C99 standard section 6.7.8 Initialization ("designated initializers"), like:

```
const static struct compiler default = {
    .ln = 1,
    // ...
};
```

and then all of the defaults assigned in a single statement.

### Nasty side-effects

This:

```
static struct symbol symtable['z' - 'A'];
static memtype sml[MEMSIZE];
static char flag[MEMSIZE];

comp->symtable = symtable;
comp->sml = sml;
comp->flag = flag;
```

is nasty. From the outside it *looks* like `compiler` is a re-entrant structure, but in actuality the memory is shared. A naive caller would pass in two different compiler instances, and then be surprised when data leaks from one to the other.

### Surprising function names

I would assume that this:

```
iscommand(tok)
```

returns a boolean, but it actually returns a pointer?

```
(*iscommand(tok))(comp);
```

It should be named something like `getinstruction`.

### Helper pointers

This:

```
    opcode0  = comp->sml[i] / comp->memsize;
    operand0 = comp->sml[i] % comp->memsize;
    opcode1  = comp->sml[i+1] / comp->memsize;
    operand1 = comp->sml[i+1] % comp->memsize;
    opcode2 = comp->sml[i+2] / comp->memsize;
```

can be somewhat abbreviated by the creation of a temporary pointer equal to `comp->sml + i`.

### Switch

This is the perfect use-case for a `switch`:

```
        if (expr->u.c == '+')
            comp->sml[comp->inscount++] = ADD * MEMSIZE + op2;
        if (expr->u.c == '-')
            comp->sml[comp->inscount++] = SUBTRACT * MEMSIZE + op2;
        if (expr->u.c == '*')
            comp->sml[comp->inscount++] = MULTIPLY * MEMSIZE + op2;
        if (expr->u.c == '/')
            comp->sml[comp->inscount++] = DIVIDE * MEMSIZE + op2;
        if (expr->u.c == '%')
            comp->sml[comp->inscount++] = REMINDER * MEMSIZE + op2;
```

Comment: `iscommand` actually returned int in a previous version. It returned a number representing the command, or zero, if the string is not a command. But then I needed a function that returned a pointer to the function related to a string, then reused `iscommand` for that.

Comment: _From the outside it looks like compiler is a re-entrant structure, but in actuality the memory is shared_. Should I define the arrays inside the structure, then? It would be a humongous array, so I should switch the pass-by-value from function `assemble` to a pass-by-reference.

Comment: I think your structure can basically remain as-is; just use `malloc` instead of assigning a reference to a static variable.

Comment: _Consider moving your variable declarations closer to where they're used_. I have adopted a coding style that explicitly specifies to [not mix declaration and code](https://suckless.org/coding_style/) and to put declarations at the beginning of the function.  On assignment-in-conditions, I watched out to not use them, but I think there is a few I wrote on automatic.

Comment: I agree with Reinderien - that coding style is 40 years obsolete.  The original reason (in the 1970s) to put declarations first was to accommodate memory limitations of hardware at that time (e.g. my first computer in 1978 only had 8K of RAM). In more modern renditions of C, the computer accommodates the human instead of the human having to accommodate the machine.  Unless you're going to code exclusively for a PDP-8, sticking with that limitation is going to impede your progress to more complex projects.